# Website to display and filter data from MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to create a website to display some information from a MySQL Database on the same server, but have no idea where to start.

I have a:
MySQL Database. This contains one table with information on items which were added on a particular date. Information includes, Title, Location and Date the item was added.

I need to:
Create a website front end which will allow me to filter by a particular date and display the Title and Locations of all devices which were checked on that date, preferably in a table format.

I am also currently running an Apache/PHP/MySQL web server on the same machine and know how to return data via JSON using PHP, but have no idea how to manipulate it into website format?

I assume I would start by allowing the user to select from a list of avaliable dates somehow, then use their selection to perform a "SELECT * FROM 'added_devices' WHERE date=?", which then returns {"Title":Bob,"Location":London,"Date":20/11/03}, {"Title":Bill,"Location":Manchester,"Date":18/12/05},

Any help would be greatly appreciated, no idea where to start!

Comment: I think google would be the best place to start for you..

Comment: If you know PHP and MySQL, your next step is to learn HTML/CSS because that seems to be what you're missing. In particular, how to build HTML forms, process their results, and generate HTML output with PHP.

Comment: Looking around, this seems to be the way to go. Looking around, there are a lot of complex methods of doing it, but that seems  the best way to get started. Thanks Marcus!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've learned in your question, you should have a look at [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php), which is web gui for mysql, written on php.